# Format Exception was unhandled in C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, decimal

I'm a beginner at this so if you can, explain what exactly is happening and why? Thanks. I'm creating a windows form to calculate the total pay and commission for employees when factoring in the type of employee they are, how many hours they worked and how much sales revenue they earned. For example, I'm entering S as employee type, 30 hours worked and 200 sales revenue. But I keep getting this error and I can't figure out why.

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

This error is coming up for

```
decimal commission = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesCommission.Text);
```

and specifically it pointing at the `(txtSalesCommission.Text)`.

Here is the code for it.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            string employeeType = txtEmployeeType.Text;
            decimal hours = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHoursWorked.Text);
            decimal revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesRevenue.Text);
            decimal commission = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesCommission.Text);
            decimal totalPay = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalPay.Text);

            txtSalesRevenue.Text = revenue.ToString("c");
            txtSalesCommission.Text = commission.ToString("c");
            txtTotalPay.Text = totalPay.ToString("c");

            //Employee Types: S   = Salaried Employees
            //                HC  = Hourly Commission Employees
            //                HNC = Hourly Non-Commission Employees  

            if (employeeType == "S")

            {
                totalPay = (300 + commission);
                commission = (revenue * .02m);
            }

            else if (employeeType == "HC")

            {
                totalPay = ((12 * hours) + commission);
                commission = (revenue * .01m);
            }

            else if (employeeType == "HNC")
            {
                totalPay = (16 * hours);
                commission = (revenue * 0);
            }

            txtTotalPay.Focus();
}
```

If you think this will come up again in another situation in my code or if there is anything that you see that could be wrong, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti this question would be closed in seconds because we on CR don't deal with broken code.

Comment: Heslacher, you're right. From last paragraph I thought he already knew how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

You should use `TryParse`. This error happen because your string is not valid decimal. You can show error if you want in this case.

```
decimal commission = 0;

if(!decimal.TryParse(txtSalesCommission.Text, out commission))
{
     //show error to the user and tell him to fill proper decimal value
     return; //exit the method
}
```

EDIT: [Decimal.TryParse Method (String, Decimal)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx) article in msdn

Comment: what does TryParse do?

Comment: Trying to Parse your string to valid decimal number. If the parsing is successful you receive the value of this parse in the previous defined commision variable. If not the value of commision stay 0. So if  the text of txtSalesCommission  is "Text123", this will return 0 for commision with my code with your it iwll throw a Format Exception.

Comment: @DerekGroves did this fix your problem ?

Comment: It did and I did the same thing for the totalpay variable but when I run the form and enter in values in the 3 text boxes, it comes up with $0.00 in the commission and total pay text boxes.

Comment: @DerekGroves what values you are running in the text boxes ?

Comment: The ones I mentioned above...I'm entering S as employee type, 30 hours worked and 200 sales revenue (hours and sales are just random made up number for me)

Comment: txtSalesRevenue.Text you are writing 200 sales revenue, this could not be parsed. You should write only 200. Use debug it will be easier to see the problems.

Comment: Well yeah of course. I didnt mean I was writing "200 sales revenue". I meant I typed "200" into the Sales Revenue text box.

Comment: well when I'm debugging i type in the values and hit calculate and the commission and total pay come out to $0.00 and then if I hit calculate again, it comes up with the exception handle and gives the same error as before but now its for         decimal revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesRevenue.Text);

Comment: I added an answer to my question for some newer code with only Parse and try catch statements but I'm getting my own error message of invalid numeric format if you wanna look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Also I'm not too familiar with tryParse and exceptions so would it be okay if I instead did Parse and did a try catch statement? Because I did this but I'm getting my own failure message of invalid numeric format when I type "S" into Employee Type, "30" into Hours Worked, and "200" into Sales Revenue.

This is my code for it:

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{ 
try            
{
            string employeeType = txtEmployeeType.Text;
            decimal hours = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHoursWorked.Text);
            decimal revenue = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesRevenue.Text);
            decimal commission = Decimal.Parse(txtSalesCommission.Text);
            decimal totalPay = Decimal.Parse(txtTotalPay.Text);

            txtSalesRevenue.Text = revenue.ToString("c");
            txtSalesCommission.Text = commission.ToString("c");
            txtTotalPay.Text = totalPay.ToString("c");

            //Employee Types: S   = Salaried Employees
            //                HC  = Hourly Commission Employees
            //                HNC = Hourly Non-Commission Employees  

            if (employeeType == "S")

            {
                totalPay = (300 + commission);
                commission = (revenue * .02m);
            }

            else if (employeeType == "HC")

            {
                totalPay = ((12 * hours) + commission);
                commission = (revenue * .01m);
            }

            else if (employeeType == "HNC")
            {
                totalPay = (16 * hours);
                commission = (revenue * 0);
            }
        }

        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Invalid numeric format. Please check all entries.",
                "Entry Error");
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Overflow error. Please enter smaller values.",
                "Entry Error");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                ex.Message,
                ex.GetType().ToString());

            txtTotalPay.Focus();

        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```